# Accessing Table in ListView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView as following:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvSample">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="Table1" runat="server">
            .
            .
            .
       </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

How can I access the table with ID "Table1" programatically? I have tried using lvSample.Findcontrol("Table1") but it didn't work. Also I don't see any list view property that gives me the table. I have to mention that there is only one table in the entire ListView.

Comment: in what context did you use `lvSample.FindControl`?  Was it inside of a particular event?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? To add rows programmatically you probably want a completely different method than server-run primitive web controls, such as using a Repeater.

Comment: I used it in Page_load event as I need to scroll to nth row of the table every time page loads.

Comment: @GrantThomas I need to scroll to nth row of the table every time page loads I have to use ListView as It's a big implementation and I cannot convert it to Gridview...